# iPhone app for Salesforce CRM

Tags: iphone, client

We are planning to develop an iPhone client application for Salesforce CRM. After a quick read from their web site we understad that, the Salesforce CRM provides an API for developing such applicataions.

Our concern is that after developing the application, how we demo this to our clients. Can we have a demo account from Salesforce?

Comment: Why ask here? Ask Salesforce.

Comment: did you ever end up building that app? how did it go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salesforce.com provides a free Developer login for Development and Demo's of features/products build for the Salesforce.com platform. 
Check out the sites:
http://developer.salesforce.com - It has lot of development resources. http://www.developerforce.com/events/regular/registration.php?d=70130000000EjHb - this is to register for free Developer edition.